# Why $|x-y|<1\implies|y|\leq |x|+1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the following passage in one of the proofs in my workbook:

$$|x-y|<1\implies|y|\leq |x|+1$$
Why is this valid?

Answer (score 3):

More generally $\left|\,|y|-|x|\,\right|\leq |y-x|$.

Which implies $|y|-|x|\leq |y-x|$.

Answer (score 2):

It is called the reverse triangle inequality. The general form of this estimation reads

${\big|}\ \|x\|-\|y\|\ {\big|}\leq \|x-y\|$

The proof uses the normal triangle inequality and can be found on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality#Reverse_triangle_inequality).

Answer (score 0):

The general answer comes from the triangle equality, as already shown.

To visualize this *particular* inequality, consider what
$|x - y| < 1$ means. 
It tells us that the "distance" from $x$ to $y$ is less than $1$.
The values that are at a distance of exactly $1$ from $x$ are $x-1$ and $x+1$;
since $y$ must be closer to $x$ than those values are, this tells us that
$$x-1 < y < x+1.$$

Now ask what the distance is from *zero* to the farther of the two values,
$x-1$ or $x+1$. If $x > 0$ then $x+1$ will be farther; if $x < 0$ then $x-1$
will be farther; if $x=0$ then both are the same distance;
but the farthest distance is $|x| + 1$ in any of those cases
(the distance to $x$, plus the additional distance to get to the value
at a distance $1$ *beyond* $x$).

So of all values in the interval $[x-1,x+1]$, none can be farther than
$|x|+1$ away from zero. Since we know $y$ is in that range, $y$ cannot be
more than $|x|+1$ away from zero. In other words, $$|y| \leq |x|+1.$$

Another way to look at this is, the interval $[-|x| - 1, |x| + 1]$,
which we can also write as $[-(|x| + 1), |x| + 1]$,
contains $x$ (either at $|x|$ or $-|x|$)
and all the values within distance $1$ from $x$
(plus some other values if $x\neq0$).
Since $y$ is within distance $1$ from $x$, 
it follows that $y$ is one of the values in that interval. That is,
$$-(|x| + 1) \leq y \leq |x| + 1.$$
But that is equivalent to $|y| \leq |x|+1.$